# Making distant object always appear larger in OpenGL without recalculating vertex positions

Tags: opengl, view, matrix, distance, perspective

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPzXN.jpg

I am rendering a 3D scene which needs to have a viewing angle that is the same as that of the human eye, however, I need objects which are distant to appear larger than they currently do in my scene.

Say I had a long, narrow rectangular prism slightly above the camera extending into the distance.  The prism would appear large close to the user, but would taper of into the distance, eventually becoming a thin, pixelated line.  This is what I am trying to prevent.
I want a way to make the prism taper of more slowly, so that more of its length is visible, without expanding the part that is close to the user.  My current solution is to split it into many every growing rectangular prisms that go off into the distance, but this approach is obviously computationally costly.

**Is there some way I can manipulate the system to make distant objects appear larger, without changing the view angle, i.e. without 'zooming in' on the scene?**  The key is that the scene must not appear distorted.  It should simply look as if the distance objects have grown.

I am not sure what avenue I would take to achieve this goal.  My original thoughts were manipulations of the view matrix, but I recognize that that may not help.

Clarification and more drawings available upon request.

Comment: For an object to "appear larger", the solid angle subtended at the view point must be larger. There are only two ways to achieve that (that I know of): the object is larger, or it is closer. There is no magic here. Perhaps if you post pictures of what you want to achieve ("I have this, I want that") people can give you more helpful suggestions...

Comment: Fixed-function or programmable pipeline?

Comment: We are using OpenGL ES 2.0, so a programmable pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for a non linear projection (not straightforward)

The [paper](http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/LOGPSM/logRasterization.pdf) or the [paper](http://liris.cnrs.fr/Documents/Liris-3429.pdf) propose a method to do that (look at the related work for other methods)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The Siggraph paper describes a solution for concave lenses, which distort the scene so that closer objects appear larger.  Is there equivalent research for convex lenses?

Comment: I think it's I3D not Siggraph. Lloyd et al paper (first link) shows the main idea and uses logarithmic warping. with normalized values in [0,1] the log increases as you want